# Robotframework fails to start firefox on Linux

Tags: python, robotframework, geckodriver

I am setting up a robot test-environment.
I can't get robot to start the firefox browser.

My environment:
Lubunto (linux) 20.04
Python 3.8.10
Firefox 93.0

I installed:

```
$ pip install --upgrade robotframework-seleniumlibrary
$ pip install webdrivermanager 
$ webdrivermanager browser firefox
```

I added my .local/bin and .local/share/WebDriverManager/bin to PATH

Installed versions:
Robot Framework 4.1.2
webdrivermanager 0.10.0
geckodriver 0.29.0

I created a file helloworld.robot:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Testcase HelloWorld
    Open Browser  https://www.knmi.nl/home  firefox
```

Running this robot test fails on:
WebDriverException: Message: Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 64

There is a file geckodriver-1.log containing:
geckodriver: error: Found argument '--websocket-port' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context

Does anyone have a sugestion how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Helio gave the solution:
order webdrivermanager to install 0.30.0:

```
webdrivermanager firefox:v0.30.0
```

Please not the 'v' before 0.30.0. Without it webdrivermanager cant find that version.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely is outdated version of `geckodriver` when managed by `webdrivermanager`.

Try to install manually the latest, 0.30.0.

Comment: Thanks Helio! One would expect webdrivermanager to know which version of the driver is needed by him. pip install --upgrade geckodriver fails. There is no geckodriver found. Asking webdrivermanager explicitly for geckodriver 0.30.0 also fails. It can't find information of that version.